# Getting the block of commands that are to be executed in the with statement

Tags: python, scope, with-statement

In reading the specifications for the `with` statement ([link](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)), I have some things I'd like to play around with. This isn't for any production code or anything, I'm just exploring, so please don't be too harsh if this is a bad idea.

What I'd like to do is grab the piece called "BLOCK" in the linked docs above, and actually tinker around with it inside of the call to `__enter__`. (See the linked doc, just after the start of the motivation and summary section.)

The idea is to create my own sort of on-the-fly local namespace. Something like this:

```
with MyNameSpace(some_object):
    print a #Should print some_object.a
    x = 4 #Should set some_object.x=4
```

Basically, I want the statements inside of the `with` block to be subordinate to the local variables and assignment conventions of `some_object`.

In my specific case, `some_object` might be a special data array that has my own column-wise operations or something. In which case saying something like `x = y + 5 if y > 4 else y - 2` might be some fancy NumPy vectorized operation under the hood, but I don't need to explicitly call `some_object`'s interface to those methods. In the namespace, the expressions should "just work" (however I define them to be inferred in the `MyNameSpace` class.

My first idea is to somehow interrupt the `with` process and get a hold of the code that goes in the `try` block. Then interpret that code when `__enter__` gets called, and replace the code in the `try` block with something else (perhaps `pass` if that would work, but possibly something that restores `some_object` back to the original variable scope with its new changed variables preserved).

A simple test case would be something like this:

```
my_dict = {'a':3, 'b':2}
with MyNameSpace(my_dict):
    print a # Should print 3
    x = 5 # When the block finishes, my_dict['x'] should now be 5
```

I'm interested if this idea exists somewhere already.

I am aware of best practices things for assigning variables. This is a pet project, so please assume that, just for the sake of this idea, we can ignore best practices. Even if you wouldn't like assigning variables this way, it could be useful in my current project.

**Edit**

To clarify the kinds of tricky stuff I might want to do, and to address the answer below claiming that it can't be done, consider the example file `testLocals.py` below:

```
my_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2}
m = locals()
print m["my_dict"]['a']
m["my_dict"]['c'] = 3
print my_dict

class some_other_scope(object):
    def __init__(self, some_scope):
        x = 5
        g = locals()
        some_scope.update(g)
        some_scope["my_dict"]["d"] = 4

sos = some_other_scope(m)
print my_dict
print x
```

which gives the following when I run it non-interactively:

```
ely@AMDESK:~/Desktop/Programming/Python$ python testLocals.py
1
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'd': 4}
5
```

Comment: can you use `with` without assigning (using `with x as f` or `with x=f`)?

Comment: Yeah, it just calls the context manager's `__enter__` function, etc. If you don't reference the thing after `with` inside the block, then it would not need the name of that thing.

Comment: You could monkey with the `globals` dictionary in the current stack frame, but the fundamental problem is that it won't work inside a function. Python statically determines which variables are local when a function is compiled to bytecode and handles locals in a streamlined fashion for better performance.

Comment: I really wish this was a standard language feature of Python. For mathematical code, `self.` and `dictionary['key']` are horribly cumbersome, making code unreadable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
import sys 
class MyNameSpace(object):
    def __init__(self,ns):
        self.ns = ns
    def __enter__(self):
        globals().update(self.ns)
    def __exit__(self, exc_type,exc_value,traceback):
        self.ns.update(sys._getframe(1).f_locals)

my_dict = {'a':3, 'b':2} 
with MyNameSpace(my_dict) as ns:
    print(a) # Should print 3
    x = 5 # When the block finishes, my_dict['x'] should now be 5 

print(my_dict['x'])
```

Comment: Doesn't this mess up the global namespace? I.e. create or overwrite a global variable `a`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something similar I tried a few months ago:

```
import sys
import inspect
import collections

iscallable = lambda x: isinstance(x, collections.Callable)

class Namespace(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        """store the pre-contextmanager scope"""
        f = inspect.currentframe(1)
        self.scope_before = dict(f.f_locals)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        """determine the locally declared objects"""
        f = inspect.currentframe(1)
        scope_after = dict(f.f_locals)
        scope_context = set(scope_after) - set(self.scope_before)

        # capture the local scope, ignoring the context manager itself
        self.locals = dict(
            (k, scope_after[k]) for k in scope_context if not isinstance(scope_after[k], self.__class__)
        )

        for name in self.locals:
            obj = scope_after[name]
            if iscallable(obj):
                # closure around the func_code with the appropriate locals
                _wrapper = type(lambda: 0)(obj.func_code, self.locals)
                self.__dict__[name] = _wrapper
                # update locals so the calling functions refer to the wrappers too
                self.locals[name] = _wrapper
            else:
                self.__dict__[name] = obj

            # remove from module scope
            del sys.modules[__name__].__dict__[name]

        return self

with Namespace() as Spam:
    x = 1
    def ham(a):
        return x + a      
    def cheese(a):
        return ham(a) * 10
```

It uses inspect to modify locals while within the context manager and then to re-assign back to the original values when done.

It's not perfect - I can't remember where it hits issues, but I'm sure it does - but it might help you get started.

Comment: This only allows you to add or remove values from `locals()` which then remain static inside the `with` suite. The `locals()` mapping applies to all code following the `with` suite uses the same local namespace so you need to be careful in cleaning up.

Comment: Yes, it's not a perfect approach, but it does somewhat head toward what the question asked for. It was intended to be used by referencing the namespace, rather than exist solely for the life of the context manager, so it attempts to wrap all callables in a closure. (Actually, on re-reading the question I see I misunderstood exactly what was asked for, Odomontious' answer is a much better approach.)