# How do you do a python 'eval' only within an object context?

Tags: python, eval, abstract-syntax-tree

Is it possible to do something like

```
c = MyObj()
c.eval("func1(42)+func2(24)")
```

in Python..i.e. have func1() and func2() be evaluated within the scope of the object 'c' (if they were member functions within that class definition)? I can't do a simple parsing, since for my application the eval strings can become arbitrarily complicated. I guess doing some magic with the ast module might do the trick, but due to the dirth of literature on ast, I'm not sure where to look:

```
import ast

class MyTransformer(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        # do a generic_visit so that child nodes are processed
        ast.NodeVisitor.generic_visit(self, node)
        return ast.copy_location(
            # do something magical with names that are functions, so that they become 
            # method calls to a Formula object
            newnode,
            node
        )

class Formula(object):

    def LEFT(self, s, n):
        return s[:n]

    def RIGHT(self, s, n):
        return s[0-n:]

    def CONCAT(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return ''.join([arg for arg in args])

def main():

    evalString = "CONCAT(LEFT('Hello', 2), RIGHT('World', 3))"

    # we want to emulate something like Formula().eval(evalString)
    node = ast.parse(evalString, mode='eval')
    MyTransformer().visit(node)

    ast.fix_missing_locations(node)
    print eval(compile(node, '<string>', mode='eval'))
```

Comment: You might have better luck just creating your own simple language and parse that with something like [pyPEG](http://fdik.org/pyPEG/)

Comment: Can you limit yourself to only the methods on the object, or do you want them to be able to call other things like globals or explicitly named other classes as well?

Comment: eval() can take 'globals' and 'locals' dictionaries as parameters.  Maybe you can populate those with your functions and pass them in?

Comment: Honestly, I think you _should_ be explicitly parsing here. It's not trivial, but that's because what you're trying to do isn't trivial. If that doesn't work, @LAK's suggestion of populating an explicit dictionary to use as a context is still probably simpler than faking it with an object. But if you _do_ want to use objects as contexts, see my answer.

Comment: Also, if "the eval strings can become arbitrarily complicated"—are they arbitrarily complicated _Python_? Can someone eval, say, `'func1(42) + func2(24) + os.system("rm -rf /")'`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want to do this, but you *can*.

The context for [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) is the globals and locals dictionaries that you want to evaluate your code in. The most common cases are probably `eval(expr, globals(), mycontext)` and `eval(expr, mycontext)`, which replace the default local and global contexts, respectively, leaving the other alone. Replacing the local context with an object's dictionary is similar to running "within" (a method of) that object—although keep in mind that "being a member function" doesn't do as much good as you might expect if you don't have a `self` to call other member functions on…

Anyway, here's a quick example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.bar = 3
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> eval('bar', globals(), foo.__dict__)
3
```

Keep in mind that `__dict__` may not be exactly what you want here. For example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @staticmethod
...     def bar():
...         return 3
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> eval('bar()', globals(), foo.__dict__)
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
>>> eval('bar()', globals(), {k: getattr(foo, k) for k in dir(foo)}
3
```

To make this work the way you want, you have to know exactly how to define you want, in Python terms—which requires knowing a bit about how objects works under the covers (MRO, maybe descriptors, etc.).

If you really need `eval`, and you really need to provide arbitrary contexts, you're probably better building those contexts explicitly (as dictionaries) rather than trying to force objects into that role:

```
>>> foo = {
...     'bar': lambda: 3
... }
>>> eval('bar()', globals(), foo)
```

This use is much closer to the Javascript style you're trying to emulate in Python anyway.

Of course, unlike JS, Python doesn't let you put multi-line definitions inside an expression, so for complex cases you have to do this:

```
>>> def bar():
...     return 3
>>> foo = {
...     'bar': bar
... }
>>> eval('bar()', globals(), foo)
```

But arguably that's almost always more readable (which is basically the argument behind Python not allowing multi-line definitions in expressions).

Comment: Thanks!! You're right - I should have thought of functions as capable of free-floating in the globals() or local() environment just as any instantiated object would. That reflects my lack of imagination with Python :)

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at the accepted answer to this question: ["Getting the block of commands that are to be executed in the with-statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485837/getting-the-block-of-commands-that-are-to-be-executed-in-the-with-statement).

This has been a helpful way for me to create my own contexts in which math operations on rectangular arrays, such as Python Pandas data frames, "just work" without needing to bother with the ugly extra Pandas syntax. For example, when I write "`a = x*y`" inside of the context, it automatically assigns `a` as an attribute to the context object, and it knows to perform vectorial operations with the context object's `x` and `y` attributes.

I've found this context stuff to be very very helpful, despite the fact that whenever I ask on StackOverflow, I often get trollish responses that it must not be what I really want to do.

You could probably get this to work for the context in which `eval` looks for functions too.

Answer (score 2):

So, I advice you to do something like this:

```
>>> class S(object):
...     def add(self, a, b):
...         return a + b
... 
>>> filter(lambda (k,v): not k.startswith("__"), S.__dict__.items())
[('add', <function add at 0x109cec500>)]
>>> target = S()
>>> map(lambda (k, f): (k, f.__get__(target, S)), filter(lambda (k,v): not k.startswith("__"), S.__dict__.items()))
[('add', <bound method S.add of <__main__.S object at 0x109ce4ed0>>)]
>>> dict(_)
{'add': <bound method S.add of <__main__.S object at 0x109ce4ed0>>}
>>> eval("add(45, 10) + add(10, 1)", _, {})
66
```

Seems like that you need. Let me explain how this works.

1. `eval` accepts locals and globals as parameters.
2. So we need to define special global context which will be "representation" of your class.
3. To do this, we need to provide as `globals` dictionary of all "valuable" **bounded methods**.
4. Starting from simples part. We have `S` class definition. How to get all "valuable" methods? Simple `filter` names from `S.__dict__` in order to check whether method name starts from `__` or not (you see, that as result we get list with 1 item - `add` function).
5. Create `target` = instance of `S` class which will be "eval context".
6. Next step is most "tricky". We need to create "bound method" from each function. To do this, we use those fact, that class `__dict__` stores functions, each function is non-data descriptor and bounded method can be fetched simply with `func.__get__(obj, type(obj))`. This operation is performed in `map`.
7. Take result from previous step, create `dict` from it.
8. Pass as `globals` to `eval` function.

I hope, this will help.

Comment: Great solution! Passing bound methods in the globals environment for eval! Thanks so much Alexey!

Answer (score 2):

The solution proposed above to populate `locals` works well in most cases, but may be problematic in case of properties (data descriptors). These are evaluated *once* when the dictionary is populated. This means that multiple references to the same variable name will always return the exact same instance, which may not be expected behavior in case of properties.

This problem can be solved by noting that `eval` expects a `locals` argument that *behaves* like a `dict` (as opposed to globals, which must *be* a `dict`). In other words, we can override `__getitem__` in your instance to resolve variable names on the fly in the context of the instance and pass it directly as `locals` attribute to `eval`. Your example can thus be implemented as:

```
class Formula(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key not in dir(self) or key.startswith('__'):
            raise KeyError(key)
        return getattr(self, key)

    def LEFT(self, s, n):
        return s[:n]

    def RIGHT(self, s, n):
        return s[0-n:]

    def CONCAT(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return ''.join([arg for arg in args])


def main():
    evalString = "CONCAT(LEFT('Hello', 2), RIGHT('World', 3))"
    print eval(evalString, {}, Formula())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This trick should work with inheritance, static methods, class methods and properties. Finally, using `dir` and `getattr` avoids the need to interact directly with `__dict__` or `__mro__`, though the results of `dir` may [not always be complete](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir).