# Pipelining pandas: create columns that depend on freshly created ones

Tags: pandas

Let's say you have the following DataFrame

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2]})
```

now I want to construct the column B = A+1, then the column C=A+2 and D = B +C. These calculations are only here for simplicity. Typically, I want to use some e.g. nonlinear transformations, normalizations etc.

what one could do is the following:

```
df.assign(**{'B': lambda x: x['A'] +1, 'C': lambda x :['A']+2})\
    .assign(**{'D':lambda x: x['B']+ x['C']})
```

However, this is obviously a bit annoying, specifically, if you have a large number of preprocessing steps in a pipeline. Putting both dictionaries together (even in an orderedDict) fails.

Is there a way to obtain a similar result faster or more elegantly?
Additionally, the same problem occurs, if you want to add a column that uses e.g. the sum of a just defined column. This, as far as I know, will always require two assign calls.

Comment: Why are you concerned about having multiple assign calls exactly? The overhead will be tiny relative to the computation time of you calculations.

Comment: just for completeness: since pandas 0.23.0, assign respects the order of keyword arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `eval`

```
df.eval("""
  B= A+1
  C= A+2
  D = B+C""", inplace=False)
Out[625]: 
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  5
1  2  3  4  7
```

If you want the calculation within the query ''

```
df.eval('B=A.max()',inplace=True)
df
Out[647]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  2
```

Comment: thanks for that hint and reminding me that I should add some more context to the question. In general, I don't want to apply something as elementary as adding a one, but rather using some kind of functions. I fear eval is not applicable in that case or am I wrong?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 you can do `df.eval('B=A.max()',inplace=True)` for the max...this is only a example too, if you can provide what function you want to contained , that would be better 
`

Comment: hmm, the functions I intend to use, differ from case to case. Often I use custom lambda functions that I want to pass. Can one do this here? Is it possible to apply the max to multiple columns as well? I assume eval parses the input line by line and therefore has the advantage of only needing to be called once, right? Is there a different way of creating new columns in pipelines?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 as far as I know , it could but ,may I asking why you need it ? check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923091/how-do-you-do-a-python-eval-only-within-an-object-context

Comment: I am just looking for a nice way to design data processing pipelines. There maybe a lot of custom functions you only need once or even more regular. I really like, how one can construct the computation in dictionaries. However, I think what I want to achieve is simply not possible without multiple assigns. I need a computation graph like e.g. dask has it. And ther one has to specify the dependencies quite explict. But thanks for pointing out the capabilities of eval