# store information from document to variable Firestore

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am doing some testing with firestore. I am wondering how i can get the values from  [each individual variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHd3u.png) in a document in firebase and store it in separate variables.

i have followed some tutorials but all they have shown is how to see the whole document:

```
result = db.collection('Doinkulator').document("DoinkulatorData").get()
print(result.to_dict())
```

with this at the output

```
{'HvorMyeForEtt': 0, 'kjopt': 1, 'HvorMye': 3, 'HvemHarMed': 'knut'}
```

Comment: Whenever you read a document, you always get the whole document in the returned snapshot.  You have to write code to extract the fields from the document snapshot into variables, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To get value from a specific field in the document, you can do:

```
hvor = doc.to_dict()["HvorMyeForEtt"]
```

You can also unpack multiple fields in one go, as shown in [Elegant way to unpack limited dict values into local variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755178/elegant-way-to-unpack-limited-dict-values-into-local-variables-in-python) and [Destructuring-bind dictionary contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955412/destructuring-bind-dictionary-contents)